# Executing a script directly vs. executing a script via the source command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, terminal

I saw a question recently where a user wanted to ensure that his script is only executed by using `source`.

My question is: what's the difference between `./test_script.sh` and `source test_script.sh`? I do know that when `source` is used the script file doesn't need +x permissions. Are there any other differences? And my second question is: in what kinds of situations is each method appropriate?

Comment: Try having a look at the manpage for the source command, there's a pretty good explanation there. `man source`

Comment: @Matt My distro doesn't have a man page for `source`. And `help source` is just 5 sentences long and basically just says the FILENAME is executed in the current shell and what the exit status can be. I'd like a more in depth explanation.